# I18n::InvalidLocaleData: I18n gem has issues in js export

Tags: ruby, string, parsing, escaping, yaml

I'm working on a **application with Rails 3.2.22.4, Ruby 2.2.7** on OS X 10.13.4. There are multiple translation files eg. en.yml, sq.yml based on the countries. While executing the command from rubymine below, errors are seen on loading the webpages.

> rake --trace i18n:js:export

- The yaml content from en.yml has been validated and it's correct. The specific line in which error is thrown once removed from file will give error in some other .yml file. The current version of gem `i18n (0.9.5)` is being used.
- Rails server starts but loading of the first page of web application breaks with same error.
- Error is thrown the code encounters i18n translation code, yml formatting is not an issue as error moves from one file to another.
- This is mostly a gem issue either i18n, Psych etc but changing multiple versions have not helped to solve.

**Error displayed in browser if tried loading the page:**

```
can not load translations from /Users/biju/projecty/config/locales/en.yml: 
#<Psych::SyntaxError: (/Users/biju/projecty/config/locales/en.yml): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 26 column 27>
```

**Error stack when tried executing rake tasks**

```
2018-07-18 16:40:51 +0530 Projecty::Application.initialize! took 1.733 sec
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
** Execute i18n:js:export
rake aborted!
I18n::InvalidLocaleData: can not load translations from /Users/biju/projecty/config/locales/en.yml: #<Psych::SyntaxError: (/Users/biju/projecty/config/locales/en.yml): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 26 column 27>
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:232:in `rescue in load_yml'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:229:in `load_yml'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:213:in `load_file'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `block in load_translations'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `each'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb:15:in `load_translations'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-0.9.5/lib/i18n/backend/simple.rb:63:in `init_translations'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:164:in `block in translations'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:163:in `instance_eval'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:163:in `translations'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:121:in `block in scoped_translations'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:120:in `each'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:120:in `scoped_translations'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:43:in `segment_for_scope'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:54:in `block in configured_segments'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:48:in `each'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:48:in `inject'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:48:in `configured_segments'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:93:in `translation_segments'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/i18n/js.rb:36:in `export'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/i18n-js-3.0.5/lib/tasks/export.rake:5:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `call'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:240:in `block in execute'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `each'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:235:in `execute'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:179:in `block in invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/biju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:172:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/task.rb:165:in `invoke'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:150:in `invoke_task'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block (2 levels) in top_level'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `each'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:106:in `block in top_level'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:115:in `run_with_threads'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:100:in `top_level'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:78:in `block in run'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/rake-10.5.0/bin/rake:33:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/bin/rake:23:in `<top (required)>'
-e:1:in `load'
-e:1:in `<main>'
```

snippet from .yml file, line 26 which is giving error.

```
    en:
  formtastic:
    labels:
      event_filter:
        source_server: "Server:"
        source_source: "Sevent_filter:"
        source_server: "Server:"
        source_source: "Source:"
        serverOption: "Server:"
        Category: "Category:"
        EventID: "Event ID:"
        Type: "Type:"
        TEA: "Target E-mail Address:"
        All: "All"
        ShWare: "ShWare:"
        Services: "Services:"
        Other: "Other"
        Any: "Any"
        Error: "Error"
        Warning: "Warning"
        Information: "Information"
        None: ""
        can_not_be_blank: "can't be blank or click on \'Any\'"

  list:
    buttons:
      previous: "Previous"
      next: "Next"
```

**EDIT**
Reconstructing the Error in rails console:

```
    trans2 = YAML.load(File.read("#{D2_DIR}/config/locales/en.yml")).with_indifferent_access
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 26 column 27
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse'
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.7/lib/ruby/2.2.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
    from (irb):18
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/railties-3.2.22.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/railties-3.2.22.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.7@yb/gems/railties-3.2.22.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/biju/projecty/script/rails:11:in `require'
    from /Users/biju/projecty/script/rails:11:in `<top (required)>'
    from -e:1:in `load'
    from -e:1:in `<main>'
```

I'm unable to get the pointers after enough search, could be a gem issue not sure though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you share the yaml file

Comment: I had commented that line and next execution of the i18n command gave errors in other fille

Comment: How can we help without your yml file? Please provide that file or describe how to reconstruct this error.

Comment: The .yml files should not be an issue, reason being if i comment the lines the error moved to another .yml. Also the same yml files are working on different setup .

Comment: Great, but how to reconstruct this error? Now that looks like "I think `I18n` not working as a must. Please, say me why?". You must check what gem, version, config file evoke error. If you want not provide en.yml, just leave few lines, that imitates parsing error.

Comment: @Leo snippet from .yml file attached, see the update for how to recontruct

Comment: if the yml file itself has no problem, could it be the tabs that's causing issue? From the yml file you've pasted here seems like the `en` is being indented in tab while others are spaced. This might sounds stupid but it happened to me once.

Comment: aware of that tab issue but here i have validated the yml.

Comment: `ruby#2.2.7`, `rails#3.2.22.4`, `i18n#0.9.5`. There is not an error in this part. So, error related to some other gem(can you provide `gemfile`?). And try to check no printed characters from locales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an OS specific issue, related to YAML library. The parsing of .yml file breaks at **can_not_be_blank: "can't be blank or click on \'Any\'"**. The below error appears only in OSX tested in multiple versions of OS x.

```
require 'yaml

2.4.1 :002 > trans1 = YAML.load(File.read("/Users/app.yml"))
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): found unknown escape character while parsing a quoted scalar at line 23 column 27
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse'
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:377:in `parse_stream'
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:325:in `parse'
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/lib/ruby/2.4.0/psych.rb:252:in `load'
    from (irb):2
    from /Users/biju/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.1/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
2.4.1 :003 >
```

The same code works in windows irb. However in OSX changing **\'Any\'** to **'Any'** helps to execute the operation. Not sure what could be the reason except that the library is installed in unix vs windows.